# Force spring boot (+thymeleaf) to return string as Plaintext not as name of template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the same error like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451255/spring-boot-thymeleaf-and-controller) but the solution is not working. 
Although we use thymeleaf, we also have some functions returning strings, which should not be interpreted as view-names.
My method returns a string, the controller is annotated with `@RestController` and the method looks like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/register/{phoneNumber}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@RequestBody String jsonObject, @PathVariable(value = "phoneNumber") Long phoneNumber) {
    return "some string";
}
```

But I always get this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "register/123456789", template might not exist or might not
>   be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

How can I force Spring to return the String as String and not interpret it as view-name?

Spring Version: Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: Could you please post your Configuration and tell us how you make your Request?

Comment: I used the getting started spring-boot gradle tutorial from the official website and just added "compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")" to my `build.grade`. It's a normal POST-Request (with curl)

Comment: If you are using '@RestController' then there is no need to include '@ResponseBody', do you have any configuration related to resolvers or Spring security?

Comment: This is strange . According to the documentation , the annotation  '@ResponseBody' can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name). For this,  Spring converts the returned object to a response body by using an HttpMessageConverter. Check in your log if this is logged: ** HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter (OnClassCondition)** If not, try register the converter.